# How to correctly clone a string from a struct in a C library into a new memory address?

Tags: c++, copy, clone

I'm trying to make a clone of my C++ object, which is a wrapper around a C 'class'. I want to API to look like this:

```
LibrdfUri uri("http://uri.com"); 
LibrdfUri uri_clone = uri.clone(); // same value but points to different memory address
```

Here is my clone function

```
    ... 

    librdf_uri *LibrdfUri::get() const { // librdf_uri is the C type that I am wrapping 
        return librdf_uri_.get(); // librdf_uri_ is a unique pointer. .get returns the raw pointer
    }

    LibrdfUri LibrdfUri::clone() const {
        unsigned char * cstr =  librdf_uri_as_string(get()); // C library utility. Returns the value of the string
        int l = strlen((const char*)cstr);
        char *uri_string = new char[l+1];
        std::strcpy(uri_string, (const char*)cstr);
        return LibrdfUri((const char *) uri_string); //uri_string now contains the same characters as cstr
    }
```

But my test case still fails:

```
TEST_F(LibrdfUriTests, TestClone) {
    LibrdfUri uri("http://uri.com");
    LibrdfUri uri_clone = uri.clone();
    ASSERT_STREQ(uri.str().c_str(),
                 uri_clone.str().c_str()); // test passes
    ASSERT_NE(&uri, &uri_clone); // test passes
    ASSERT_NE(uri.get(), uri_clone.get()); // test fails, the addresses are the same. 
}
```

Can anybody see what is going on here?

## Edit:

Here is the full class of `LibrdfUri`, in case its helpful.

```
    class LibrdfUri {
        struct deleter {
            void operator()(librdf_uri *ptr);
        };

        std::unique_ptr<librdf_uri, deleter> librdf_uri_;

    public:
        LibrdfUri() = default;

        [[nodiscard]] std::string str() const;

        explicit LibrdfUri(const std::string &uri);

        explicit LibrdfUri(librdf_uri *uri);

        [[nodiscard]] librdf_uri *get() const;

        LibrdfUri clone() const;

    };

   // implementation

    void LibrdfUri::deleter::operator()(librdf_uri *ptr) {
        librdf_free_uri(ptr);
    }

    LibrdfUri::LibrdfUri(const std::string &uri) {
        librdf_uri_ = std::unique_ptr<librdf_uri, deleter>(
                librdf_new_uri(World::getWorld(), (const unsigned char *) uri.c_str())
        );
    }

    std::string LibrdfUri::str() const {
        auto cstr = (unsigned char *) librdf_uri_as_string(get());
        std::string s = (const char *) cstr;
        return s;
    }

    librdf_uri *LibrdfUri::get() const {
        return librdf_uri_.get();
    }

    LibrdfUri::LibrdfUri(librdf_uri *uri)
            : librdf_uri_(std::unique_ptr<librdf_uri, deleter>(uri)) {}
```

## Edit2

On a suggestion from a commenter I have changed my `clone` function to

```
    LibrdfUri LibrdfUri::clone() const {
        return LibrdfUri(librdf_new_uri_from_uri(get()));
    }
```

However the clone still doesnt behave as intended::

```
    LibrdfUri uri("http://uri.com");
    LibrdfUri uri_clone = uri.clone();
    std::cout << &uri << ", " << &uri_clone << std::endl;
    std::cout << uri.get() << ", " << uri_clone.get() << std::endl;
```

Outputs:

```
0x7ffc46e17400, 0x7ffc46e17408
0x55c0cf693120, 0x55c0cf693120
```

## edit 3

Also, the output of

```
    LibrdfUri uri1("http://uri.com");
    LibrdfUri uri2("http://uri.com");
    std::cout << &uri1 << ", " << &uri2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << uri1.get() << ", " << uri2.get() << std::endl;
```

is

```
0x1fff000560, 0x1fff000568
0xed98a60, 0xed98a60
```

But the output of

```
    LibrdfUri uri1("http://uri1.com");
    LibrdfUri uri2("http://uri2.com");
    std::cout << &uri1 << ", " << &uri2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << uri1.get() << ", " << uri2.get() << std::endl;
```

is

```
0x7fff89c40120, 0x7fff89c40128
0x55a2e4c12120, 0x55a2e4c12470
```

Comment: If you are working with [this API](http://librdf.org/docs/api/uri.html), there's `librdf_new_uri_from_uri` function which makes the clone you want.

Comment: Wow good spot there, thanks. However it did not solve the problem (see edits) - I guess the problem must be on the 'other side', perhaps with the assignment?

Comment: What do you get with `LibrdfUri uri1("http://uri.com"); LibrdfUri uri2("http://uri.com");`?

Comment: @Eljay Ive updated the question, looks like my code isn't doing what I think its doing.

Comment: It seems the library you use performs some kind of caching of `librdf_uri` instances, and hands out the same instance for the same URL.

Comment: Interesting, you could be right. But then I do have to wonder why bother including a `librdf_new_uri_from_uri` method in the first place. I'll look for an alternative strategy that doesn't involve clones.